# how to optimize Extracting all_simple_paths in Networkx library in python?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, directed-graph, network-analysis

I have a directed graph **G** and a list of all sources and targets. sources and targets are all two nodes which have at least one path between them.
Now I want to find all simple paths between sources and targets.

**df_short_path** is a Dataframe which consists sources and targets.

```
for index, row in df_short_path.iterrows():
     print (list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, row['source'], row['target'])))
```

graph **G** has  1818 **Nodes** and 3380 **Edges** and size of **df_short_path** is 252454.

Here is my problem:

when I run the code, it takes too long to even run the loop once and I also face lack of memory after some time.
does anyone have any suggestion to optimize this library or an alternative algorithm for it? (I also tried with setting a cutoff but didn't help)

thanks for your help :)

Comment: Is your graph weighted? You may want to take a look at graph tool. And do you really want to retrieve all simple path or only all shortest paths?

Comment: So you're creating a list of all simple paths between a source and target node in a graph of 1818 nodes, and making 252454 of these lists? Sounds like you're gonna need terabytes of memory regardless of how optimised the algorithm is

Comment: @Sparky05 : no, it's not a weighted graph. actually I have the list of all shortest paths and I need list of all simple path based on the list of shortest path.

Comment: @Danoram: thanks for your comment. do you know any alternative way?

Comment: Sounds like dynamic programming might be an option here. If your algorithm is able to remember (store) paths already travelled you could significantly cut down on repetitive searches. e.g. If you find all simple paths between a node A and node B then you want to find all simple paths between another node C and node B, if the algorithm comes across node A you'll be searching all those paths you've already found between A and B again. This will happen every time you call all_simple_paths on a new pair of nodes.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Do you really need to store all the paths in lists, and the lists in a dataframe, or would a lazy approach suffice (a generator that produces the results of `nx.all_simple_paths` on demand, which are themselves lazy and produces the paths on demand)?

Comment: @Timus : I need to store all simple paths so I can use it my regression test and other analysis. On demand results doesn't solve my problem. But do you have any suggestion  for on demand result? Maybe it can also be helpful.

Comment: Is your regression test for finding changes to the graph?

Comment: @Danoram : To sum up, I need to regress an attribute of one node on the same attribute of the other node listed in shortest paths and then use average lengths of all simple paths between these two nodes as a moderator variable.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm out of ideas on how to efficiently run one loop to find just all simple paths between two nodes of a graph that size. Even small graphs of 50 nodes with 100 edges times out my machine. I think you might have to consider different options for your analysis sorry.

Comment: Bad news: [Finding the number of simple paths between 2 nodes is #P-complete](http://jgaa.info/accepted/2007/RobertsKroese2007.11.1.pdf), which means most likely  very hard (a polynomial-time algorithm for solving a #P-complete problem, if it existed, would solve the P versus NP problem by implying that P and NP are equal). The only way to tackle your problem efficiently would be to exploit the specific structure of your graph, if it has any features that would allow that.

Comment: @Danoram Can confirm, no luck here either.